# How to share database on two pc?

Tags: c#, mariadb

```
string connectionstring = "datasource = 192.168.1.124; Database = dblibrary;user = root;Convert Zero Datetime=True";
```

Guys I've got an error of  "**`Host '192.168.1.134'` is not allowed to connect to this mariaDB Server**" but I've already granted privilege to this host.

[image]

Comment: You might also want to show your MariaDB settings.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sir .134 is my ip, and .124 is my other laptop ip I'm trying to share its database to .134.

Comment: Check that the ports are open on the windows firewall

Comment: @KevinSmith Then he wouldn't get that exception thrown. MariaDB is actively rejecting the connection, Windows is not.

Comment: @Eisenvielge You need to share your MariaDB configuration settings with us, but remember to omit any passwords.